# Failure to deploy ray actor to flask app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ray

When trying to deploy a ray actor on to heroku using flask (local deployment works fine) I get the following error message:

```
 ValueError: After taking into account object store and redis memory usage, the amount of memory on this node available for tasks and actors (-25.38 GB) is less than -4727% of total. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
```

I haven't seen this error anywhere, does anyone know what the solution is?=

Comment: Hmm Ray automatically detects the machine memory and check if the available memory is enough to run Ray. It looks likethe memory detection logic doesn't seem to work properly with Heroku (it says there's -25GB memory in your machine for some reason?). Can you show me your ray.init or ray.start command?

Comment: 'ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True, log_to_driver=False) 'which returns: 
' -- Starting Ray with 1.56 GiB memory available for workers and up to 0.8 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).'